# Optimalize sql syntax

Tags: php, sql

I have this 3 sql questions:

```
$producent = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("
            SELECT FieldValue 
            FROM `xy8vx_rsform_submission_values`
            WHERE SubmissionId = '$id' AND FieldName = 'Producent'
            "));

$model = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("
            SELECT FieldValue 
            FROM `xy8vx_rsform_submission_values`
            WHERE SubmissionId = '$id' AND FieldName = 'Model'
            "));

$nr_ser= mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("
            SELECT FieldValue 
            FROM `xy8vx_rsform_submission_values`
            WHERE SubmissionId = '$id' AND FieldName = 'Nr seryjny'
            "));
```

Is it posible to get those 3 values with one sql question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use IN clause.

```
 SELECT FieldName , FieldValue 
 FROM `xy8vx_rsform_submission_values`
 WHERE SubmissionId = '$id' AND FieldName IN ('Producent', 'Model', 'Nr seryjny')
```

And of course you need to use a loop to fetch the result.

```
// $sql is the above sql
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$result = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
  $result[$row['FieldName']] = $row['FieldValue'];
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: You got a little mistake in mysql_fetch_assoic -> mysql_fetch_assoc

Answer (score 1):

To fetch the 3 values in 3 rows:

```
SELECT FieldValue 
FROM `xy8vx_rsform_submission_values`
WHERE SubmissionId = '$id' AND 
FieldName in ('Producent', 'Model', 'Nr seryjny')
```

or, to fetch the 3 values in 3 columns:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT FieldValue 
    FROM `xy8vx_rsform_submission_values`
    WHERE SubmissionId = '$id' AND FieldName = 'Producent') as Producent,

    (SELECT FieldValue 
    FROM `xy8vx_rsform_submission_values`
    WHERE SubmissionId = '$id' AND FieldName = 'Model') as Model,

    (SELECT FieldValue 
    FROM `xy8vx_rsform_submission_values`
    WHERE SubmissionId = '$id' AND FieldName = 'Nr seryjny') as NrSeryjny
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$id_1=x;
$id_2=y;
$id_3=z;

$name_1="NAME X";
$name_2="NAME Y";
$name_3="NAME Z";


SELECT FieldValue 
FROM `xy8vx_rsform_submission_values`
WHERE ((SubmissionId = $id_1 AND FieldName = $name_1) or (SubmissionId = $id_2 AND FieldName = $name_2) or (SubmissionId = $id_3 AND FieldName = $name_3));
```

Now, you have to fetch your result into an array of 3 rows.

Answer (score 1):

Learn to and use the [SQL IN operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp).

Answer (score 0):

a single query will produce result of these 3 query

```
$producent = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("
        SELECT FieldValue 
        FROM `xy8vx_rsform_submission_values`
        WHERE SubmissionId = '$id' AND (FieldName = 'Producent' OR FieldName = 'Model' OR FieldName = 'Nr seryjny')
        "));
```